# How to resolve this SqlDataReader "Possible null reference assignment" warning?

Tags: c#, null, sqldatareader

I just cannot figure out what is needed to resolve the warning about the possible null reference assignment in the following case:

```
item.UniqueId = Convert.IsDBNull(reader["UniqueID"]) ? string.Empty : reader["UniqueID"].ToString()
```

If the field value is NULL, it should set the property to an empty string, otherwise it should set it to the field value converted to a string. The field is defined as PK, varchar(11), not null.

if I define the UniqueID property as `string?` then the warning goes away, but it cannot be `null` so I don't want to do that.

I was under the impression that `ToString()` cannot return a `null` result.

Comment: *"ToString() cannot return a null result"* - Incorrect. The return type of `Object.ToString` is `String?`.

Comment: If the field is defined as `not null`, then when would you ever get a DBNull object?  Could you not just do `reader["UniqueID"].ToString() ?? string.Empty`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @codeMonkey's comment, the warning can be resolved by checking for the `null` return of the `ToString()` method.

```
item.UniqueId = reader["UniqueID"].ToString() ?? string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't code like this. I write extensions that I use with my implementations with `IDataReader`. And this covers all DB providers I use, for example `MySqlDatareader`, `SqlDataReader`, `OracleDataReader`

```cs
public static string GetStringValue (this IDataReader r, sting f, string d) // f - field, d - default
{
    if (DBNull.Value.Equals(r[f]) || r[f] == null)
        return d;
    
    return r[f].ToString();
}
```

Usage

```cs
string x = null;
if (reader.Read())
    x = reader.GetStringValue("fieldName", "defaultValue or null");
```